# nested foreach loops with return expression into stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I got a problem with turning my nested for each loops into a stream.

```
for (PickOrder pickOrder : pickOrders) {
    for (PickOrderLine pickOrderLine : pickOrder.getPickOrderLines()) {
        if (pickOrderLine.getQuantity() > quantityOnHand.get(pickOrderLine.getProductCode())) {
            return productCollection.findByCode(pickOrderLine.getProductCode());
        }
    }
}
```

That is my for each loop and I wanna convert it into a stream. I tried it with that:

```
pickOrders.stream()
    .flatMap(pickOrder -> pickOrder.getPickOrderLines().stream())
    .filter(pickOrderLine -> pickOrderLine.getQuantity() > quantityOnHand.get(pickOrderLine.getProductCode()))
    .findFirst();
```

It does not work that way and I would really appreciate your tips and help! Thanks

Comment: It should work. What exactly are you returning in your second snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't comment yet to ask for clarification, so I'll post an answer instead:

It looks like this should be working. However, the only thing that is in the for-loop that is not in the stream is the return statement `productCollection.findByCode(pickOrderLine.getProductCode())`.

You could fit this in with:

```
pickOrders.stream()
                .flatMap(pickOrder -> pickOrder.getPickOrderLines().stream())
                .filter(pickOrderLine -> pickOrderLine.getQuantity() > quantityOnHand.get(pickOrderLine.getProductCode()))
                .map(pickOrderLine -> productCollection.findByCode(pickOrderLine.getProductCode()))
                .findFirst();
```

Comment: Nice! Good to hear!